# Creating a fake JavaScript exposed filter in Drupal 7 Views module

Tags: hooks, views

In this website I'm building there's a page with a Views list of people, divided into categories.
I've exposed a category filter and a name filter to visitors.

Since the list isn't long, I would like to show all the items on page load and use the exposed filters as "fake" filters. Those will not actually make a request to the database, but call a JavaScript function that will go through the list and hide the unwanted items using CSS.

I can create my own filters, but then the category filter will not auto update when a new category is created.
I've seen that I can use `MYTHEME_preprocess_views_exposed_form` hook to change it to how I want, but then the page will still download and run `auto-submit.js`, which is the CTools JS file that Views module uses for auto submitting. I can remove it with `MYTHEME_js_alter`, but it seems like a lot of effort - and mostly wasted computational time slowing the page load - for a simple task.

Does anyone know a better way to accomplish this? Am I just overreacting over a few lines of code?

Thanks guys, hope everything is clear.

EDIT:

About 5 seconds after posting I've realized that I could use `auto-submit.js` with the JavaScript too. So all I need to do is remove the action of the form and add `onSubmit` that'll point to my script.

Comment: I'd be tempted to create a cached callback to populate the filter with your categories, it'd probably run to about 5 lines of code and has to be less heavy than views adding them.

Comment: Actually, I looked for the quickest solution.
I also like the fact that in case JavaScript is disabled, the filter fallbacks to the normal views' filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I used:

I created a new module named "My Views' Client Side Filters".

In the module's `.module` file I added:

```
<?php

function my_views_client_side_filters_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    $form['#attributes']['onsubmit'] = 'return exposedFilterOnSubmit();';
    drupal_add_js('sites/all/themes/MY_THEME/js/MY_JS_FILE.js');
}
```

Which resulted in the HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="return exposedFilterOnSubmit();" action="MY FORM DESTINATION" method="get">
```

And `sites/all/themes/MY_THEME/js/MY_JS_FILE.js`:

```
function isEmpty(str) {
    return (str.length === 0 || !str.trim());
}
var departmentAllShown = true;
var nameAllShown = true;
(function ($) {
    function reloadNames(name) {
        $('.views-row').each(function() {
            if($(this).find('.doctors_view_row_title').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
                $(this).css('display','block');
            else
                $(this).css('display','none');
        });
        nameAllShown = false;
    }
    jQuery.extend({
        exposedFilterHider: function()
        {
            //Handle url (JavaScript only now enabled)
            if(!isEmpty(window.location.search))
                location = "MY_SITE_LOCATION/FORM_PAGE";

            var department = $('#edit-field-department-value')[0].value;
            var departmentIndex = $('#edit-field-department-value')[0].selectedIndex;
            var name = $('#edit-title')[0].value;

            var nameIsEmpty = isEmpty(name);

            if (departmentIndex != 0)
            {
                $('.item-list').each(function() {
                    if ($(this).children().first().text() === department)
                    {
                        $(this).css('display','block');
                        if (!nameIsEmpty)
                            reloadNames(name);
                        else
                            if (!nameAllShown)
                            {
                                $('.views-row').css('display','block');
                                nameAllShown = true;
                            }
                    }
                    else
                        $(this).css('display','none');
                });
                departmentAllShown = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Enable all categories if not already
                if (!departmentAllShown)
                {
                    $('.item-list').css('display','block');
                    departmentAllShown = true;
                }

                if (!nameIsEmpty)
                    reloadNames(name);
                else //Enable all names if not already
                    if (!nameAllShown)
                    {
                        $('.views-row').css('display','block');
                        nameAllShown = true;
                    }
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

function exposedFilterOnSubmit()
{
    jQuery.exposedFilterHider();
    return false;
}
```

Sorry I don't explain any further, I'm kind of stressed in time. If someone asks a specific question I promise to answer.

Hope this helps anyone!

BTW, although the code is a bit long it works spectacularly and runs swiftly.

Remember to change the classes! You might need to change things a bit since my layout may not be the same as yours.

**My classes:**

`.views-row` - Entire "person" row (The name container is somewhere inside and there are a few of those in every category)

`.doctors_view_row_title` - Name container

`.item-list` - The category container

Good luck guys!